# A Better alternative to display Hierarchical Data than using TreeView

Tags: design-patterns, guidelines, hierarchy, checkboxes, tree

I am a ASP.net Developer and am looking out for other alternatives to Treeview control. Reason behind is shipping too much of viewstate information for each request. Functionality of treeview would be to show menu structure with a Checkbox beside it. User selects checkboxes posts the data back and i add it to their global quick navigation slot. `Similar to pick your gadgets and i will add it to your wall` like thing. I am also looking into Quince from Infragistics but nothing striking shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong but the pattern which you seem to be hinting at is that of faceted navigation.

Faceted search or navigation is an increasingly popular method of organizing data that would otherwise be hierarchically displayed in a fixed structure. With faceted navigation, the user can pick what's important to them. With each facet selection, the effect of selecting other facets can be fed back into the other facet selection buttons. It's popular in e-commerce environment where the user has a good idea what they are looking for but wants to see their choices in context of similar items - or rather, the *company wants to show* similar items in the same context.

Depending on whether you have already collected other relevant information from the user, some facets can be pre-selected.

Note: This may not be appropriate depending on your context and user's expectations, not to mention the organization of your data. For example this pattern is not great for browsing the entire set of items.

For more information see Welie's ui pattern: http://bit.ly/k4SZS5

Comment: could you please complete that sentence, I'm not sure if

Comment: This weelie.com site looks really interesting. Upvoted the answer because of the link.

Comment: The keyword is "hierarchical" though, which facets themselves aren't. They're just two dimensional tags, really, so you'd have to build something on top of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are two other discussion related to this:

[Best design for displaying list under a list of items ?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6859/best-design-for-displaying-list-under-a-list-of-items)

[What's the best way to view a deep hierarchy?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/whats-the-best-way-to-view-a-deep-hierarchy)